# Is it possible to validate that a distribution of numbers has been manually altered?

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's assume that a professor is manually altering specific grades for a few students. Is it possible to check with some statistical method that the grades are the originals or not? For example for this dataset. Given the fact that he/she is doing it for a small amount of students like 5% overall.
[grades dataset](https://pastebin.com/5HGf3nr3)

This is the frequency of the distribution in a histogram.
[image]

Comment: Sometimes the fine structure of a grade distribution is a hint at manipulation, as when there is heaping (e.g. many students scrape a pass) that can't be interpreted as a side-effect of a marking or grading scheme. I don't think there is any white magic to tell which originals may have been changed without  more detail. The limiting case is clearly futile here: Two grades are 66, but I will tell you one was changed. Which one? So, you need more handles than you are telling us about.

Comment: I was thinking something like if we can trace it in a way for example.
If the numbers between 1 - 6 are appear most frequently (more than one time). and numbers between 7 - 10 appear only one time, it is kind of suspicious. I don't know maybe there are way out from the normal distribution?

Comment: I don't see that the normal as reference distribution helps here at all unless teachers exceptionally are instructed or expected to grade on a normal curve. The trouble with spikes is that they occur for all sorts of reasons: a student was sick, some students did no work, one student is exceptional, one question was understood by just a few people who got maximum marks, whatever. Trivially, if you show original marks and changed marks, the differences are evident, but I don't know what else you can expect.

Comment: There is always https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law but I suspect not much help in your specific application. I am afraid @NickCox is right here and there is little statistical science can offer you.

Comment: @mdewey We agree and here is an extra twist. Even if the marks are percents 0 to 100 that is too small a range to look at first digits, or so I suspect. The principle of looking for fine structure in the distribution (e.g. histograms or spike plots with no binning)  remains the best single idea in my view.

Comment: I created a frequency histogram from the data and I updated my post. Does it help now in any way? I mean you can see from 7 to 10 the distribution seems impossible to occur naturally. But how can I prove it?

Comment: Thanks for the histogram, but I don't agree. I have been handling distributions of marks for many years and am surprised by nothing here. In statistics as in all other spheres of life you need more than suspicion to substantiate malpractice. Also, it's a good principle never to talk about proof outside logic or pure mathematics. Wise statisticians Mosteller and Tukey were bang on talking about "indications" as what data may give.

Comment: Yes I agree with you about "you need more than suspicion to substantiate malpractice " part. That's why I am asking if there is a mathematic formula or a cause-effect relationship that I can validate scientifically my suspicion.
My suspicion just trigger my curiosity. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please note that the plot is quite deceptive because the value axis is nonlinear.  The gap between 3.5 and 5 will be striking when the plot is drawn correctly as a histogram.  That changes nothing about the validity of the remarks by @NickCox: no mathematical formula will demonstrate *any* amount of modification by the teacher, simply because you have no basis to discriminate the unmodified grade distribution from a modified one.